# View actual sent time in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm having a problem where I send e-mails from within Powerpoint's sharing feature, but they only get sent later when I open Outlook's main window. This feature is quite annoying and if there's a solution for this, it also solves my followup problem.

The "sent" time displayed in Outlook is the time I originally wanted to send the e-mail. In actual fact the e-mail was merely placed in the outbox until I opened the main Outlook window at a later time. The true sent time is whenever the outbox gets synced, but I can't seem to find a way to see that time.

Comment: Have you looked at the full mail headers? [Displaying Full Message Headers in Microsoft Outlook](http://its.yale.edu/how-to/article-displaying-full-message-headers-microsoft-outlook-windows)

Comment: @DavidPostill I just checked and they're blank for sent e-mails

Comment: They are blank if the e-mail is sent internally using Exchange within your company (never goes out to the Internet). Can't you have Outlook open already when you are using PowerPoint's sharing feature?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding yourself to the outgoing address list?  Note that some email services, such as Gmail, automatically treat any email with the same From: and To: addresses as spam and don't deliver it, so you might need to have a second email address for yourself to make this work.

Comment: -1 What does this have to do with the question?